# C# variable[#] in if statement where the # will be given later

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, variables, syntax

I don't really know how to ask this question, my brain stopped.

I have some variables named tank1, tank2, tank3....

I want to use only one "if" statement with using the "tank" part of the variable and then adding its number after other actions.

if (tank + 1.ToString() > 5)
like it's
if (tank1 > 5)

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a List or array of tanks? List<Tank> tanks() could be used later as tanks[0], tanks[1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a `List<Tank>` if tanks are sequentially numbered with no gaps. You'll use it like:

   `if(tanks[index] > threshold) // do whatever`
2. Use a `Dictionary<string, Tank>` if there's no method to your naming madness. It will be used like this:

   `if(tanks[key] > threshold) // do whatever`

Answer (score 2):

Make your variables an array `int[] tank;` 
tank[0], tank[1], instead of tank1, tank2

Than you can use `if (tank[i] > 5)`.

Comment: List<int> tanks = new List<int> { tank1, tank2, tank3}; if (tanks.All(tank => tank > 5)) ...

Comment: @David, for reference types yes, for int it looses the idea of a variable cause you make a copy of the value. A change of tank1 would not be reflected in your list.

Answer (score 1):

List tanks = new List { tank1, tank2, tank3};

if (tanks.All(tank => tank > 5))